# Remover 'public' da URL - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, htaccess, public

Estou acessando meu site assim:
http://localhost/site/public

Gostaria de digitar apenas http://localhost/site porquê quero que isso funcione quando eu colocar no domínio também.

Tem algum modo de resolver isso sem ser por alterações de pastas e sim somente via código ? Não entendo quase nada de .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Boa tarde Diego, use os snippet apenas para html,css,js que possa reproduzir os problemas. Outras linguagens não podem ser reproduzidas por ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolução** - Não sei se é a melhor. Segue abaixo:

Eu recortei o arquivo **.htaccess** e **index.php** da pasta **public** e colei na pasta raiz do meu site.

E dentro do **index.php** alterei o caminho das pastas que dão start na aplicação.

De

```
require __DIR__.'../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'../bootstrap/start.php';
```

Para

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Mas será que vai ter que ser sempre assim ? É que nesse caso eu estou dentro de uma pasta **dentro** da pasta **www** (public_html) da hospedagem.

Acredito que não, mas...

Comment: teve algum problema com o passar do tempo? com os assets... ?

Comment: Nunca tive. Mas agora não faço mais assim. Eu subo tudo o projeto do Laravel em uma pasta acima da **public_html** e apenas coloco dentro da pasta **public_html** o conteúdo da pasta **public** do Laravel. Roda belezinha... com PHP superior a 5.6, no caso da minha versão do Laravel.